# How to find the most connected node of particular relationship type in neo4j using cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Can some one help me to find the most connected node of particular relationship type in neo4j using cypher query.

Suppose I have

Node1      Node2     Relationship
A             B             follows
A             C             follows
B             D             follows

A             D             follows

Here Node D is the most connected node.of particular relationship type "Follows" .so how to find this node using cypher query?

Thanks in Advance

---

(Edit):
i found my answer tnx Martin Preusse

```
    MATCH (n)<-[r:FOLLOWS]-()
    RETURN n, count(r) AS num
    ORDER BY num desc
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this if the direction of the relationship matters (will only return `A` and `B`):

```
MATCH (n)-[r:follows]->()
RETURN n, count(r) AS num
ORDER BY num
```

Or this if you don't need the direction (i.e. the node `D` will be returned as well):

```
MATCH (n)-[r:follows]-()
RETURN n, count(DISTINCT r) AS num
ORDER BY num
```

Comment: Thanks @martin-preusse , but how can i find node D that follows by A and B

Comment: If the direction does not matter you can use the second query from the update.

Comment: I don't think you need to add `DISTINCT` in the second case, it would imply you can get the relationship twice in the same "direction", and get counted twice for one node and no time at all for the other node, i.e. the results would be incorrect.